# How to connect Google Colab to Tableau?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tableau-api, google-colaboratory, tabpy

I install "tabpy"  library. After that i check the setting of Tableau and load the server name(localhost) and port(9004).  I am getting error. can you please tell me how to connect the Google colab and Tableau if possible?

Comment: localhost means that the server is running on the same machine as Tableau. That is probably not the case. Please edit your question and clarify where you have installed tabpy.

Comment: I installed  the "tabpy" in Google colab.

Comment: Install TabPy with `pip install tabpy` command and run it with `tabpy` command. Now you can connect to the running instance. Documentation is here - https://github.com/tableau/TabPy/blob/master/docs/server-install.md